# Plot dimple(d3.js) chart in deck.js section

Tags: svg, d3.js, deck.js, dimple.js

I would like to insert a [dimple](http://dimplejs.org/) plot into a [deck.js](http://imakewebthings.com/deck.js/) presentation. The code below online puts the plot in the body at the background. But I would like to have the plot displayed in the section class. I think I have to change something in `var svg = dimple.newSvg("body", 800, 600)`. Because of my very limited javascript skills I have no idea what to change exactly. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
<section class="slide" id="test-section">
 <h2>test section</h2>      
  <script type="text/javascript">
       <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
       <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v1.min.js"></script>
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("body", 800, 600);
    var data = [
      { "Word":"Hello", "Awesomeness":2000 },
      { "Word":"World", "Awesomeness":3000 }
    ];
    var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
    chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Word");
    chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Awesomeness");
    chart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
    chart.draw();
  </script>
</section>
```

If only the included the specific section class code in my question. If needed the complete code can be found [here](http://commercial-excellence.nl/example.zip). The index page in the is located in the introduction folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things need fixing:

First, you can't put a script tag inside of another script tag. You should move the code that loads d3 and dimple to the head of the document:

```
...
    <script src="../modernizr.custom.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v1.min.js"></script>   
</head>
```

Second, as you suspected and John points out, something with `dimple.newSvg` is wrong. You probably want  `var svg = dimple.newSvg("#test-section", 800, 600);` so the graph is only added to the test-selection slide, not all of the slides.

I would actually go one step farther and change the html a little bit so you can control precisely where the graph appears:

```
 <h2>Graph Title</h2>
 <div id = "graphHere"></div>  
 <h3>Some more text about the graph below the graph</h3>
```

To make the graph appear between the text, just change the selection passed to dimple to the id of the div we've created:

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#graphHere", 800, 600);
```

Finally, chart.js is doing some weird resizing the graph since it is too big to fit on the slide. Without digging through the source of chart.js, we can fix the problem by creating a smaller graph:

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#graphHere", 400, 200);
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the look of deck.js so I just pulled it down and had a play.  I then came back and found Adam had basically explained everything I just found out.  You need to put a div within the slide and add the svg to that, otherwise the deck scaling code duplicates the chart.

First add a div to the relevant slide:

```
<section class="slide">
    <div id="myChartDiv"></div>
</section>
```

Then add the references to the set at the bottom (or the header if you like):

```
<!-- Required JS files. -->
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="core/deck.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v1.min.js"></script>
```

then the dimple code below that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#myChartDiv", 800, 600);
    var data = [
      { "Word":"Hello", "Awesomeness":2000 },
      { "Word":"World", "Awesomeness":3000 }
    ];
    var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
    chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Word");
    chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Awesomeness");
    chart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
    chart.draw();
</script>
```

I hope that hopes

John

Answer (score 1):

I've never used deck.js but have you tried:

`var svg = dimple.newSvg(".slide", 800, 600);`

or

`var svg = dimple.newSvg("#test-section", 800, 600);`

Let me know if that works.  If not I'll take a look at your code.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this thread is from a long time ago, but let me add one thing in addition to Adam's answer.
At least on dimple v2.1.2 + deck.js v1.1.0 + Firefox 34.0, the graph is corrupted in Adam's example.
It seems that the size of the div tag must be explicitly set:

```
<div id="graphHere" style="width:400px;height:300px;"></div> 
...
<script>
 var svg = dimple.newSvg("#graphHere", 400, 300);
 // plotting function goes here 
</script>
```